# How to align checkbutton in ttk to the left side

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment, ttk

I want to configure style`style.configure('TCheckbutton', background=theme, foreground='white', anchor=tkinter.W)` of `tkinter.ttk.Checkbutton` to align that checkbutton to the left side, because now it is in a center. Big thanks to every answer :)

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Are you certain you want to change the style rather than changing how you add it to the window with `grid` or `pack`?

Comment: @Jakub Blàha let me know if that worked for you

Comment: I tried to use the `grid`, but that does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear.

Here is some code to illustrate what pack left, right, and no assignment will do and what anchor e, w, and no assignment will do.

This should give you a better idea of how to use pack vs anchor and when to use it.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()

packLabel = Label(root)
packLabel.pack(side = LEFT)
packLabel.config(text = "Packed LEFT")

pack2Label = Label(root)
pack2Label.pack()
pack2Label.config(text = "no Pack side")

pack3Label = Label(root)
pack3Label.pack(side = RIGHT)
pack3Label.config(text = "Packed RIGHT")

anchorLabel = ttk.Label(root,width = 50, background = "green", anchor = 'e')
anchorLabel.pack(side = BOTTOM)
anchorLabel.config(text = "anchor = 'e'")

anchor2Label = Label(root,width = 50, background = "orange", anchor = 'w')
anchor2Label.pack(side = BOTTOM)
anchor2Label.config(text = "anchor = 'w'")

anchor3Label = Label(root,width = 50, background = "black", fg = "white")
anchor3Label.pack(side = BOTTOM)
anchor3Label.config(text = "no anchor while packed BOTTOM")

checkButton = ttk.Checkbutton(root)
checkButton.config(text = "Checkbutton anchor = 'w'")
checkButton.pack(anchor = "w") # anchor the pack for ttk.

root.mainloop()
```

The resulting program should look like this:
[image]

Comment: I cant use the anchor option, because I m using `tkinter.ttk`. Using option `-anchor` results to an error `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-anchor"`.

Comment: @Jakub: you can anchor in `.pack()` for ttk. I updated my answer with example.

Comment: Glad I could help. I did some research for this one and learned some stuff myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for the `anchor` option. It takes a string representing a point on a compass (eg: `"w" = "west"`, meaning the text is anchored to the left)::

```
Label(..., anchor="w").grid(...)
```

Comment: `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-anchor"` I m using `tkinter.ttk`.